# Why my does matplotlib figure only show one plot when I try and plot multiple plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to produce a line plot of the total number of cases over time comparing three countries, so multiple line plots on the same figure. I've created a function that grabs the appropriate data and creates the dataframe for it to be plotted. I then loop and try to plot the data for each country. Whenever I run the code, only the data from the last country is shown. Why is this? I've looked around for answers on plotting lines on the same figure and it should allow you to plot on the same figure.

```
countries = ['United Kingdom', 'US', 'India']
colours = ['green','red','blue']
def line_plot_ofcountries(countries, colours, data):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    for i in range(len(countries)):
        data = get_total_confirmed_ofcountry(countries[i], time_series_cases)
        plt.plot(data.index, data, color=colours[i], lw=5)
    plt.ylabel('Total cases')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

line_plot_ofcountries(countries, colours, time_series_cases)
```

This is the output for the graph
[image]

For information of what the get_total_confirmed_ofcountry() function does:

```
def get_total_confirmed_ofcountry(country, data):
    country_total = data.iloc[:,4:].apply(sum, axis=0) 

    country_total.index = pd.to_datetime(country_total.index) 
    
    return country_total
```

I'm getting data from a .csv file that contains rows of countries, with columns of dates and confirmed COVID cases as values (link to the data can be found below). The function returns a dataframe returning a cumulative number of cases over time for a country by applying the sum function over a row a country.

Link to the data can be found here if anyone is interested:https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

Comment: Check what's in `data` - you may have the same values for every country, so all plotted lines are the same and the last one in blue shows up on top.

Comment: What does the function `get_total_confirmed_ofcountry` do? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Mr.T Yes I should've probably explained what that does. I've edited the post with its explanation.

Comment: Why is `country` not used in this function?

Comment: @Mr.T Oh yes, I see now where I've went wrong. I've for some reason calculated all cases for all countries. I feel silly now, I've been looking at this for ages, thank you for pointing it out for me!